# Menu 'checkbox' com transição suave, sem o uso de "visibility:;" ou "display:none;"

Tags: html, css, checkbox

Estou com um pequeno menu aqui, que possuí o uso de overflow:hidden; / max-height:; e height:; para fazer uma transição suave ao clicar no checkbox e exibir os subs-menus, porém não estou conseguindo exibir de forma suave a class 'SUB 2' ao clicar na mesma e exibir os 'links 3' de forma que eles recuem suavemente com o transition:; já utilizei 'display:none;' mas ele não recua suavemente, já usei o 'visibility:;' porém ele não acompanha relativamente a subida de outros objetos caso for adicionados depois dos 'links 3', pois não estou conseguindo recuar os 'links 3' do 'SUB 2' ao clicar no 'checkbox', seria possível fazer ele se comporta como os outros acima?? o 'menu' e 'SUB 1' que recuam suavemente e relativamente aos outros objetos ao clicar no 'checkbox'?? não sei como fazer o  'SUB 2' se comportar como as class 'menu' e 'SUB' que deram certo!

```css
input{ display:;}

.menu{ width:200px;}

.rd1:checked ~ ul{ max-height:300px; height:auto; transition:all 0.4s linear;}
.rd2:checked ~ ul ul{max-height:300px; height:auto; transition:all 0.4s linear;}
.rd3:checked ~ ul ul ul{max-height:300px; height:auto;  transition:all 4s linear;}
 
.menu ul{overflow: hidden; max-height:0px;transition:all 0.4s linear; }

label#lb1{ background-color:#09F; position:relative; padding:5px; display:block;}

.menu ul li{ padding:3px; }

.menu ul li a{ background-color:#FFC488; padding:5px; display:block;}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
<input type="checkbox" class="rd1" id="t1" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" class="rd2" id="t2" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" class="rd3" id="t3" checked/>

<label for="t1" id="lb1">MENU</label>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">LINKS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">LINKS</a></li>
  <li><label id="lb1" for="t2">SUB</label></li>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">LINKS 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">LINKS 2</a></li>
     
  <li><label for="t3" id="lb1">SUB 2</label></li>
       <ul>
         <li><a href="#">LINKS 3</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">LINKS 3</a></li>
       </ul>
  </ul>
   
</ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A opção que encontrei é invertendo a ordem dos inputs no HTML para conseguir fazer direito. Pois o 3 nível só faria sentido ser aberto se o 2 já estiver aberto.

Para entender melhor veja o exemplo como ficou.

**OBS:** repare que agora a ordem dos `inputs checkbox` está invertida no html, se vc quiser tem como com CSS voltar para a ordem, mas como vc deve dar `display:none` neles nem vai precisar acredito...

```css
input{ display: inline-block;}

.menu{ width:200px;}

label#lb1{ background-color:#09F; position:relative; padding:5px; display:block;}

.menu ul li{ padding:3px; }

.menu ul li a{ background-color:#FFC488; padding:5px; display:block;}

.menu ul, .menu ul ul, .menu ul ul ul {
    overflow: hidden; 
    height:0px;
    transition:all 0.4s linear; 
}

#t1:checked ~ ul {
    height: 300px;
}
#t2:checked + #t1:checked ~ ul ul {
    height: 100px;
}
#t3:checked + #t2:checked  ~ ul ul{
    height: 170px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
    <input type="checkbox" class="rd3" id="t3" />3
    <input type="checkbox" class="rd2" id="t2" />2
    <input type="checkbox" class="rd1" id="t1" />1

    <label for="t1" id="lb1">MENU</label>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">LINKS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LINKS</a></li>

    <li><label id="lb1" for="t2">SUB</label></li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">LINKS 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LINKS 2</a></li>
        
            <li><label for="t3" id="lb1">SUB 2</label></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">LINKS 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LINKS 3</a></li>
            </ul>
    </ul>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Complicado! kkk, pois quanto mais for adicionado 'subs' mais confuso fica, talvez seja melhor utilizando o display e esquecer a suavização

Comment: Menu arvore do windows não tem transição suave, acho que é logo para evitar complicação e agilizar o processo

Comment: @ElienayJunior cara esses ul dentro de ul etc confunde um pouco a cabeça sim. Vc pode usar classes para isso, ai vc pode usar tipo: `.menu .sub .sub-2 .sub-3 { }` para ter certeza que está interagindo com o elemento certo. []´s